Can I request to see the content of some deleted comments?
A week ago I asked in MSE a question and got an answer to my initial problem and some follow up questions in comments by a user, who unfortunately a few days ago decided to delete these highly informative comments.
That's sad, because these highly insightful elaborations answered my problem and unfortunately I missed to record them on my pc. Moreover I'm pretty sure that other users facing similar problems could profit from them.
So my question is if there are possibilities to get access to these deleted comments.
For instance, do I have the right to demand from moderators - which presumably should have the permissions to access deleted comments - to get a copy of deleted comments? If not, why does this violate some policy of this site?
Which possibilities do I else have?
[Note that I not ask to redelete the deleted comments in the public thread as this would violate the rights of the user's interest who from certain reasons not known to me decided to delete them.]

As written, this is a request for support (how can I currently do something/how does this work/please do something that's already possible), not a feature request (please change something about the site). Note that if all you're asking is for comments on a specific question to be undeleted, then that should, generally, be first asked for in an "in need of moderator intervention" flag on the post where the comments were, as that's the most appropriate way to communicate that request to moderators, who are the ones that would need to do it. If that fails, then a meta post might be reasonable.
